# How do you pronounce "figure it out" quickly?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, fast-speech-rules

It it pronounced "figurtitout" or "figurtout"? which one is more natural/correct? I always try to go for the first but I find it harder to pronounce than the second one (Cuz I hate those many t's in a middle of a word)

Thanks

Comment: You have three 't's in the first example. Did you really mean that?

Comment: Do you have the same trouble with *kept it out* or *cut it out* or *turned it out* or *tuned it out* or *thought it out*? Is it only your own production of these words that gives you trouble, or is listening to it said ever a stumbling block for knowing just which words were said to you?  Do you ever have any trouble distinguishing whether Americans are saying *figure it out* or *figured it out* or *figured out*? Do *treatment, tectonist, tartlet, taste-test, teletext, testament, tintist,  tetrant, tête-à-tête* all trip off your tongue untroubled by tripled *t*’s?

Comment: Are confusing *figured it out* with *figure it out*?

Comment: @tchrist It might be the syllabic /r/ before a KIT/schwa causing the problem there.

Comment: Attempting to ask or answer questions about actual pronunciation in the silence of English text is a losing proposition. All you'll get is technical phonetics and/or opinions. Otherwise you're discussing Picasso with the blind

Comment: @TChrist I do have trouble pronouncing this type of words. I also do have problems with listening. I tend to confuse the d's with t's (when spoken quickly) so I can confirm what you said.

Comment: @Tinfoil I can definitely tell the difference between the two words but it's hard for me to notice any difference when listening to both words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pronunciation varies widely by region.  In Canada and the northeast US, your first option, which includes the i sound, would be normal, but with our standard replacement of interior t's by d's.  Hence, figyeridout.